# check if url has '/?' thru tuckey urlrewrite

Tags: tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I need to check thru URL rewrite if the URL has question mark after 'search-product-list/'. I'm using tuckey. Here's the current rule:

```
    <rule>
            <from>^/n/search-product-list/(.*)$</from>
            <to last="true" type="permanent-redirect">/ttsvr/search-product-list/$1</to>
    </rule>

    <rule>
            <from>^/search-product-list/(.*)$</from>
            <to last="true" type="forward">/n/force-redirect/fitmycar-webdesign-73?query=$1</to>
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

i was able to get the result I expected by doing this:

```
        <rule>
                <from>^/search-product-list/(.*)?q(.*)$</from>
                <to last="true" type="forward">/n/force-redirect/fitmycar-webdesign-73?query=$1</to>
        </rule>
```